# Computer needs several attempts to power on? (Much like a bad car)

Tags: power, temperature, computer-architecture

I've had a look at the available [stack exchange forums](http://stackexchange.com/sites) and i have concluded that this one might be the most relevant for my question, though it does adhere to personal computing. Please inform me if this is the wrong place to ask this.

My question is perhaps a bit abstract. My laptop has in recent years had trouble turning on. But it hasn't been *unable* to turn on - it has just required a modest number of attempts! **It's behavior when i want to turn it on has been very similar to that of a car which has trouble starting cold.**

When i try to turn my computer on it will often require 10 tries or so, unless
it has been on very recently (past 10-15 minutes). A failed attempt to turn on will activate the "Power ON" LED, and start turning the fan and then shut down after 2-3 seconds. If there is a CD/DVD in the disk reader it would start spinning too before the sudden shut down.

If the computer is connected to its power cord, it will after a failed startup reattempt to power on by itself after 2-3 seconds again. If it is merely connected to its battery it will just stay off after a failed attempt.

If it fails to turn on, it will **not be able to power the screen** before the sudden shut down! Thusly, once i see the screen backlight turn on and the "American Megatrends" logo, I know it has succeeded. **Once the computer successfully boots it behaves normally.**

This might be completely incidental, but i find that i have some increased luck to power it on while it's cold by tilting the laptop at different angles.

I am very much in the beginner, hobbyist stage of electronic doo-dads and blippety-bloops and don't fancy myself experienced enough to go probing around with my multimeter to find the fault - **I simply don't know what to look for!**

I don't have much hope for "solving" this (to me) negligible issue, but i find it extremely interesting! So i have come to you, the more experienced electronic engineers, for ideas on what might be causing this. Does anyone know what sort of components might be worn out, or what could be failing to cause this kind of problem?

Comment: It's broken, take it to the lab or get a new one. Repair questions are off-topic here.

Comment: Possibly better on SuperUser not EE.SE. Either way something is broke and repair questions without any specific understanding of the underlying circuits are off-topic on EE.SE.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Not really broken. Once it turns on there's no problems whatsoever. It _will_ reliably turn on, it just _will_ take a minute or two.

Comment: @TomCarpenter Thank you for migrating it to the proper site.

Comment: @TerjeGundersen I call it broken as it is not fully functional. Anyway, the question was migrated to presumably more suitable site, so maybe you will get some help here..

Comment: Your question is so broad, all we can do it guess. There are so many possibilities of what it could be; motherboard, power switch, solder joint, corrupt BIOS, and on and on. You have given no details about the computer, so there is no way for anyone to even consider equipment specific answers.

Comment: @CharlieRB Do you have any suggestions for where i would begin looking for further details?

Comment: Edit your question to give the basic problem and include the brand & model. Also, run some diagnostics to see if there are any issues that can lead you to the problem. Then update your question with those details.

Comment: Try ATX resetting. Remove the battery and power cord from your laptop. Press the power button and hold for 15 seconds(without any power source connected). Plug in only the power cord, leaving the battery out of the laptop. Try booting up the computer. If it boots properly, then shut it down, put the battery back in, and boot it up again. If the computer does not boot up with only the power cord in it, then unplug the power cord and hold the power button for 15 more seconds. Reset the battery in the computer, plug in the power cable, and boot up the computer

Comment: re-seat your memory modules (remove and re-insert them a few times) then test them.... http://www.memtest.org/

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem with a PC. Once I turned it on it would restart after 2-3 seconds. What turned out to be the problem was that the power cable was slightly unplugged, and powered only part of the motherboard. To clarify, this is the power cable from the PSU to the motherboard in the case.

Now, there is no guarantee this is the exact problem you are having, but it looks like a power issue, if it can turn on properly. But usually with laptops it is cheaper to simply buy a new one.

Edit
As other people have clarified it can be many things: a short somewhere etc. I do not think it is firmware related, because it boots properly after a couple of attempts. This means that the firmware is operating properly. I would say it is a mechanical issue somewhere e.g. cable being unplugged etc.

Perhaps you can open it up and look for some indicator LEDs, or an alphanumeric display, if you have one, when you power it up. Consult the motherboard manual.

Comment: I have had this computer to bits to replace the screen previously, and it is very well possible that the motherboards connection to both the battery and the external power supply (power cord) isn't great, due to mistakes on my part. This is a good place to begin looking. Thanks.